# How would you set up a tensorflow cluster of multipe TPUv2-8 (tpu-vm)?

Tags: tensorflow, google-compute-engine, cluster-computing, tpu

I have two tpu-vms (v2-8) running on GCE with software version *tpu-vm-tf-2.8.0*. I would like to perform distributed deep learning with tensorflow using both vms, i.e with a total of 2x8 = 16 cores.

For distributed learning on 8 cores I set the strategy as follows:

```
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='local')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

What do I need to change in order to connect multiple vms? I feel like this will probably involve *MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy* but I'm not sure how. Note that I did manage to make it work on Pytorch XLA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tf.distribute.TPUStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/TPUStrategy) will work for both TPU device (v2-8, v3-8) and TPU Pod slice (v2-32, v3-32, v2-64, ...). Valid pod slice configurations don't include v2-16, but they include v4-16.

If you want to create TPU pod slice v2-32 with TF2 image, you can use `--version=tpu-vm-tf-2.9.1-pod` and `--accelerator-type=v2-32`:

```
gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm create my-tpu-32 \
--zone=europe-west4-a \
--accelerator-type=v2-32 \
--version=tpu-vm-tf-2.9.1-pod
```

Note: `my-tpu-32` will have 32 TPU cores. You will need to change 'local' to the TPU pod slice name (i.e. `my-tpu-32`).

```
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='my-tpu-32')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

You won't need to provide `tpu='my-tpu-32'` above if `TPU_NAME` envirnment variable is set to `my-tpu-32`.
The training on TPU Pod slice will look like this (note setting `TPU_LOAD_LIBRARY=0`):

```
TPU_NAME=my-tpu-32 TPU_LOAD_LIBRARY=0 python3 my_training.py
```

The rest of the code can be the same (possibly updating batch size and learning rate, some details [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/training-on-tpu-pods)).